# Flutter wrong toDate() conversion

Tags: flutter, datetime

In my app the user can select a showDatePicker which is then stored in a firestore document under a timestamp field called "giorno":

[image]

the problem is that when I try to retrieve it inside the app with a streambuilder

```
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    
       // other code...

       for (var d in snapshot.data.docs) {
         DateTime date = DateTime.parse(d['giorno'].toDate().toString());
         print(date);          
       }
```

the data is wrong by 1 day, it's 1 day earlier:

```
I/flutter (11487): 20-Aug-2021
```

Another strange thing is that this weird behavior happens apparently only on the android emulator, and not on the actual phones.

Do you know if I'm doing anything wrong or is it just an emulator bug?

Comment: Have you checked the date set on the emulator?

Comment: @tomerpacific I just thought about it :) you are right, that's the problem!!! emulator is set to a wrong timezone!!!! Sorry for that, and thank you for taking time to answer

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that the emulator was set to a wrong timezone. Problem solved :)